# Retrieving view data in a view composer

Tags: php, laravel

If I do the following in this view composer:

```
View::composer('product.edit', function($view)
{
    $viewdata = $view->getData();
    dd($viewdata);
});
```

I can see in the output that exists 'language_id', however I don't know how to retrieve it, since `$viewdata['language_id']` will throw an exception.

How should I go about this?

**Update:**

The accepted answer led me to discover that when a presenter is involved in this operation, the model will be available in the offset, here is the final code:

```
View::composer('product.edit', function($view)
{
    $data = $view->offsetGet('product')->toArray();
    echo $data['language_id'];
    exit;
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try this:

```
$language_id = $view->offsetGet('language_id');
```

Following public methods are available in the `$view` object (An instance of `Illuminate\View\View`)

```
0 => string '__construct' (length=11)
1 => string 'render' (length=6)
2 => string 'renderSections' (length=14)
3 => string 'with' (length=4)
4 => string 'nest' (length=4)
5 => string 'withErrors' (length=10)
6 => string 'getEnvironment' (length=14)
7 => string 'getEngine' (length=9)
8 => string 'getName' (length=7)
9 => string 'getData' (length=7)
10 => string 'getPath' (length=7)
11 => string 'setPath' (length=7)
12 => string 'offsetExists' (length=12) 
13 => string 'offsetGet' (length=9)
14 => string 'offsetSet' (length=9)
15 => string 'offsetUnset' (length=11)
16 => string '__get' (length=5)
17 => string '__set' (length=5)
18 => string '__isset' (length=7)
19 => string '__unset' (length=7)
20 => string '__call' (length=6)
21 => string '__toString' (length=10)
```

You may also try something like this:

```
if($view->offsetExists('language_id')) {
    $language_id = $view->offsetGet('language_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Worth noting you can also access view data using the attribute syntax (at least starting Laravel 8):

```php
$languageId = $view->product->language_id ?? null;
```